# Обновлении ссылки (wcf) в web приложении asp

Tags: c#, wcf, entity

Для обработки данных и для взаимодействия web приложения используется wcf служба. Используем Entity Framework. В последнее время обновление ссылки на службу занимает очень много времени и обновление происходит не с первого раза, обновление прерывается ошибкой.

[image: Ошибка при обновлении]

При предварительной загрузке ссылки на службу в браузере время обновления падает примерно в 2 раза, но это все равно долго.

Можно как-то уменьшить время обновления или хотя-бы убрать ошибку?

Comment: Чья служба? Ваша или сторонняя?

Comment: Наша, все крутиться на 1-м сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причин медленной работы может быть много. Вот основные:

- утечка памяти;
- плохой канал связи с сервером;
- тяжелое приложение на том же сервере.

Эти причины вам все равно придется устранять.

---

Если же вам надо исправить "здесь и сейчас", чтобы ошибка не мешала при разработке - надо изменить ваш рабочий процесс. Вместо того, чтобы сначала публиковать службу, а потом добавлять ее в Service References - сохраните wsdl-описание службы, а потом добавьте в Service References его.

Делается это так.

1. Когда веб-служба обновлена - запускаем ее локально.
2. Открываем в браузере ссылку `http://localhost/ваша/служба.svc?singleWsdl`
3. Сохраняем файл и передаем его тому, кто делает клиент к службе
4. Тот, кто делает клиент для службы, получает этот файл
5. Добавляется или обновляется Service Reference, вместо адреса службы пишите путь к wsdl-файлу
6. В файле конфигурации заменяете адрес `http://localhost/ваша/служба.svc` на правильный адрес службы

Также вместо шага 6 можно заменить адрес конечной точки в файле.

---

Если и клиентом, и сервером занимается один разработчик - то можно обойтись без wsdl-файла, и ввести `http://localhost/ваша/служба.svc` в качестве адреса службы. Или `http://localhost/ваша/служба.svc?singleWsdl` в качестве адреса wsdl-файла.

Также есть вариант генерации клиента с помощью программы `wsdl.exe`, без использования Service Reference.

Если и клиент, и сервер находятся в одном решении - то можно сделать вовсе без Service Reference: контракты выделяются в общую библиотеку, подключиться к службе можно через [`ChannelFactory<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms576132(v=vs.110).aspx)